# Fonts in \freekfont with polyglossia

Tags: fonts, polyglossia

I try to use package `polyglossia` because I write in Greek language but I cannot use various textfonts and I don't understand why.

In my preamble I write

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{greek}
\newfontfamily\greekfont {here is my problem not all fonts can be used}
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Well, not all fonts have Greek, so not all can be used. I think, you'd need to distinguish your `\greekfont` from `\setmainfont`. 
It should be possible to define multiple languages in `polyglossia`, if you need this feature. Else, I think that LuaTeX can load fonts as XeTeX, but can also use `babel`.

Comment: Select a font that supports Greek script. For example, Latin Modern and the TeX Gyre fonts do not, but Computer Modern Unicode does. All the fonts from GFS (the Greek Font Society) and most from SIL and Microsoft do, as well.

Comment: “... to use package polyglossia because I write in Greek” is a wrong assumption. You can use `babel` and `xgreek`, too.  Here is an example for Polytonic Greek with LuaLaTeX and `babel`: https://github.com/latex3/babel/blob/master/samples/lua-polygreek.tex .